# Install uwsgi 1.2.5 via pip

Tags: python, nginx, python-2.7, django

Welcome,

Currently I'm trying to install latest uwsgi on my VPS (Ubuntu 11.10) based on instruction from the site
http://projects.unbit.it/uwsgi/wiki/Quickstart

```
pip install uwsgi
```

During compilation I see some errors:

```
...
[gcc -pthread] spooler.o
*** uWSGI compiling embedded plugins ***
[gcc -pthread] plugins/python/python_plugin.o
Complete output from command /usr/bin/python -c "import setuptools;__file__='/etc/apt/sources.list.d/build/uwsgi/setup.py';exec(compile(open(__file__).read().replace('\r\n', '\n'), __file__, 'exec'))" install --single-version-externally-managed --record /tmp/pip-joud1I-record/install-record.txt:
running install

In file included from plugins/python/python_plugin.c:1:0:

plugins/python/uwsgi_python.h:2:20: fatal error: Python.h: No such file or directory

compilation terminated.

using profile: buildconf/default.ini

detected include path: ['/usr/lib/gcc/i686-linux-gnu/4.6.1/include','/usr/local/include', '/usr/lib/gcc/i686-linux-gnu/4.6.1/include-fixed', '/usr/include/i386-linux-gnu', '/usr/include']

Patching "bin_name" to properly install_scripts dir
...
```

And finally I see:

```
...

[gcc -pthread] spooler.o

*** uWSGI compiling embedded plugins ***

[gcc -pthread] plugins/python/python_plugin.o

----------------------------------------
Command /usr/bin/python -c "import setuptools;__file__='/etc/apt/sources.list.d/build/uwsgi/setup.py';exec(compile(open(__file__).read().replace('\r\n', '\n'), __file__, 'exec'))" install --single-version-externally-managed --record /tmp/pip-joud1I-record/install-record.txt failed with error code 1 in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/build/uwsgi
Storing complete log in /root/.pip/pip.log
```

Has anyone any suggestions how can I install latest uwsgi?

Regards,
Grzegorz

Comment: What turned out after following all advice above is that instead of running pip3 install uwsgi I should run the command as root: sudo pip3 install uwsgi

Answer (score 38, accepted):

> plugins/python/uwsgi_python.h:2:20: fatal error: Python.h: No such file or directory

To compile C extensions for Python you need Python development files:

```
$ sudo apt-get install python2.7-dev
```

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian: Please, have a look at the related http://askubuntu.com/q/499206/306605. Thanks.

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian: ... or http://stackoverflow.com/q/24822829/1346705

Comment: Had the same error on Debian Wheezy with Python 3.4, this helped, thanks!

Comment: a have `python2.7-dev` installed and still see the error

Answer (score 1):

Just so will be here in case someone else comes across this problem:

Even though we had installed python2.7-dev successfully we still got this error.

What apparently was the problem was gcc's inability to find the libraries which were included in the build script pip was trying to run.

We actually ended up getting the uwsgi pip zip:

- https://pypi.python.org/packages/source/u/uWSGI/uwsgi-1.9.20.tar.gz

and then changing it manually like with the following steps.

First, we unzipped it:

```bsh
tar xvzf uwsgi-1.9.20.tar.gz
```

Then, we edited the file `uwsgiconfig.py`, replacing line 213,

```py
cmdline = "%s -c %s -o %s %s" % (GCC, cflags, objfile, srcfile)
```

To say this instead:

```py
cmdline = "%s -I/usr/include/libxml2 -c %s -o %s %s" % (GCC, cflags, objfile, srcfile)
```

Basically, letting gcc know that your libraries are at `/usr/include/libxml2` (this was our case at least).

After that, we rezipped the folder:

```bsh
tar cvf uwsgi-1.9.20.tar uwsgi-1.9.20/
gzip uwsgi-1.9.20.tar
```

And used `pip` with that gzip file:

```bsh
sudo pip install uwsgi-1.9.20.tar.gz
```

And that worked. Hope that helps someone!

Comment: your gcc installation is broken if can't find headers that are installed via standard packages

Answer (score 0):

To install under Cygwin via `pip`, need the following packages:

- gcc-core
- gcc-g++ (probably)
- libcrypt-devel
- libintl-devel
- python3
- python3-devel